# Javascript passing variable to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function DoThings()
{
 var txt = txtbox.value;

 txt = /* passed info from code behind */
}


$(function() { var Tags=[ txt ]; $( "txtbox2").autocomplete({source: Tags});});

</script>
```

but i want to move it to the page. im unsure how i send the variable "txt" to my jquery function

Comment: Is your question about how to assign var txt with a value comeing for a server-side variable?

Answer (score 1):

Make the function have a return statement.

```
function DoThings() {
   var txt = txtbox.value;
   txt = /* passed info from code behind */
   return txt; //return it.
}

$(function() { 
    var Tags=[DoThings()]; $("#txtbox2").autocomplete({source: Tags});});
```

Comment: what does those '[]' surrounding `DoThings()` do?

Comment: Odds are that any autocomplete function is going to be ajaxy stuff and, being asynchronous, won't let you return anything.

Comment: @Quentin That's true, in ajax way, an callback function should be provide.

Comment: sorry, ive tried to update my method. i was hoping to avoid posting the whole thing and just grab a quick answer. but as ive said, i cant call the method from inside the jquery as i need to call it after keyup
**note, if you have a pre built string, calling the method inside the juqery array works a treat

Comment: Sorry for the confusing edit updates - @user1168783 you should possibly update your question with the updated methods, or as xdazz suggests provide a jsfiddle sample you can both work on.